# How to remove rows with nan from array in Python using np.isnan?

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

This is my code:

```
with open(r'filename.dat') as f:
for line in itertools.islice(f, 19, None):
    line = line.strip()
    columns = line.split()
    lam = columns[0]
    lam1 = np.array(lam)
    flux = float(columns[1])
    flux1 = np.array(flux)
    data = np.column_stack((lam1,flux1))
    data = data[~np.isnan(data).any(axis=1)]
    print(data)
```

I get this error:

TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: What is your example input and output you're trying to achieve... what you're doing here (looping over a file, splitting it manually, stacking columns etc...) seems like a lot of work as opposed to using loadtxt or similar...

Comment: Essentially I have a .dat file that contains a header, and then wavelength and the corresponding flux values. Some flux values are indicated as "nan" (i.e., low flux). There probably is a much easier way to remove the rows with nan than the way I am doing it.

Comment: Have you tried just loading your file with `np.loadtxt` and specifying a suitable `skiprows=` and `usecols=` and seeing what happens? Something like `data = np.loadtxt('filename.dat', usecols=[0, 1], skiprows=19)`

Comment: That did the trick! Now data = data[~np.isnan(data).any(axis=1)] works. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could more easily import the data using the the numpy function [genfromtxt](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.genfromtxt.html) and then drop the NaNs using a simple slice notation operatcion:

```
data = np.genfromtxt('filename.dat')
data = data[~np.isnan(data)]
```

That way when you import the data it will already be a `ndarray` and numpy operations will be easier to apply. Then using the slice notation you are selecting the rows that are not `~` a NaN `np.isnan()`.